# Kubernetes network config

Tags: kubernetes

Precondition: the kubernetes cluster have 1 master and 2 worker. The cluster uses one CIDR for all nodes.
Question: how to configure network to pod on worker1 can communicate with pod on worker2?

Answer (score 2):

Kubernetes has its own service discovery and you can use define `service` for communicate. If you want to communicate or send request to `worker2` then you have to define a service for `worker2`. Suppose you have a worker `add-service` and you want to communicate with it, then you have to define a service for `add-service` worker like below

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: add-service
spec:
  selector:
    app: add
  ports:
    - port: 3000
      targetPort: add-service
```

Then from worker1 you can user `add-service` to communicate and kuberntes will use service discovery to find the exact worker. Here is a **hackernoon** detail [article](https://hackernoon.com/how-to-develop-go-grpc-microservices-and-deploy-in-kubernates-5eace0425bf8) about how to create pod, deployment, service and communicate with between them.

Answer (score 0):

A kubernetes cluster consists of one or more nodes. A node is a host system, whether physical or virtual, with a container runtime and its dependencies (i.e. docker mostly) and several kubernetes system components, that is connected to a network that allows it to reach other nodes in the cluster. A simple cluster of two nodes might look like this:

[image]

[image]

You can find more answers [here](https://medium.com/google-cloud/understanding-kubernetes-networking-pods-7117dd28727)

[When the cluster use one CIDR for all nodes, the pod will be assigned ip address from one subnet.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fCXQO.png)

Comment: Thank for your answer! In my case, the cluster uses one CIDR for all nodes that is mean the pod on all nodes will be assigned ip address belong to one subnet.

Comment: if you use one subnet for all nodes, I think they can communicate together, but not for container inside the docker, you need to use `--network host` for your container, refer it here https://docs.docker.com/network/host/

Comment: When using --network host, host ip address will be assigned for container. This isn't case which I looking for.